# Is it possible to run a function in background without returning to calling thread?

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to call a function to work in background, but when it finishes it should "just stop" and not continue in the calling thread.

Currently I am doing this:

```
Task.Run(() => { MyFunction(); });
/* next code line */
```

In this case the code launches MyFunction() in background thread and continues its execution to **next code line** without waiting when MyFunction() finishes (what I want), but when MyFunction() finishes it returns back to calling thread and also continues from **next code line** (what I do not want). So, **next code line** is executed twice: immediately after launching MyFunction() and after MyFunction() finishes.

What I should do to avoid running code from **next code line** after MyFunction() finishes its task?

EDIT:
All I want is to execute MyFunction in background. I do not need any awaiting - main code should just call MyFunction() and go further without awaiting for MyFunction() to finish.

Comment: That's exactly the opposite of what a thread means.  You may be looking for `await`.

Comment: Your assertion that the calling thread will *also* start executing the same code it had already run *again* when the background task has finished is false.  That's not how threads work.  If the code is being run multiple times, then the calling thread is doing something to explicitly call it multiple times, as a result of code not shown.

Comment: @SLaks No, the OP specifically said that they *want* the calling thread to continue executing after starting the background task (and not after it has finished, as `await` would do), but that *that isn't what's happening*.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what you want to happen in more detail.  The "next line" will not run twice.  Do you want sync or async?  Do you want "next line" to run now or later?

Comment: What I want is just to execute MyFunction() in background.

Comment: @Kibernetik: Those two terms are opposites.

Comment: "synchronously in background" This makes zero sense to me. I can't understand what it means. It's either synchronous or in the background.

Comment: Forget "synchronously" - I need it to run in another thread in background.

Comment: So basically you want to start a new thread. `new Thread(MyFunction).Start()`? Your question seems really long for something a "start new thread in C#" google search would tell you.

Comment: new Thread() is not available in UWP. Your reply seems really you don't read a question attentively.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of the behavior you're seeing. Your code already does what you want it to do, so something else is going on.

Comment: It was a question. That's what the question mark at the end of the snippet means. You could have taken that to google like I just tried. First result for "uwp new thread" is a very in-depth article about how to do asynchronous (not synchronous!) programming in UWP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've provided already does what you want it to do. If the behavior seems incorrect, you should take a look at `MyFunction`, and see if it's doing something you don't want.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
private static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting new task...");
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" - Task says 'Hello'");
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        Console.WriteLine(" - Task says 'Goodbye'");
    });
    Console.WriteLine("This line should not run twice.");
    Console.WriteLine("Going to sleep while waiting for our task to finish...");
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your code sample! This means that the problem is somewhere else. Although Thread class is not available in UWP.